# Resistor Keyboard Vs Matrix Keyboard

Tags: resistors, matrix, keypad

I'm part way through my prototye macro keyboard which currently consists of 4 keypads with 16 keys on each - so 64 keys in total. The method I'm using is the 3 wire, resistor based one.R1,R2,R3 and R17 are 10k, R18 is 1M. (see circuit section below)

It all works perfectly fine, 64 keys using 4 analog pins on the micro controller (currently an Arduino Leonardo clone but it'll be a Teensy later) - So there's nothing wrong but I'm looking at reasoning for going the matrix keypad method which is what most keyboards have.

What are the pros of the matrix method over the resistor method. Pin count seems to be a big advantage on the resistor method 1 more pin gives me 16 more buttons. Pros and cons of each method?

```
5v1 is +5v
P1 is an analogue pin on the arduino
G1 is ground.
SB1A1 + SB1B1 are the 2 connections for button 1 
SB2A1 + SB2B1 are the 2 connections for button 2 
SB3A1 + SB3B1 are the 2 connections for button 3
etc
```

[image: Section of circuit]

Comment: ***Matrix keypad does not use analog pins***, so is more scalable, say, to 64 keys or even 128 or 256 keys. You might like to read my answer to the following Q&A to see more details of my argument: (1) "Multiple GPIO Buttons vs Matrix Keypad":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98440/multiple-gpio-buttons/98451#98451.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted matrix for membrane so the quantity-cost thing doesn't apply.

Comment: Matrix keyboards offer *determinism* while analog button combinations are limited in key number before accuracy becomes a concern.  The resistor thing is sort of an "Arduino hack" leveraging the fact that there's now a free halfway decent ADC.   Matrix keyboards are a mature technology and tradition that evolved when ADCs were expensive -  they could be and often were built from early mask-ROM MCU's which were a decade or more away from growing an ADC.  It's unlikely you'd find *multiple* analog key assemblies in a product, unless it was a retrofit to the original design.

Comment: If you are going to build a "keyboard" to type on or similar, do it the ordinary way, only perhaps with an MCU filling the same function as a fixed function keyboard encoder.

Comment: The analog version can lead to incorrect results if multiple keys are pressed. Scanning a matrix can avoid this.

Comment: Resistors and ADC are occasionally used in production devices: https://hackaday.com/2017/06/26/hacking-an-inspection-microscope/